# malloc/free and new/delete compatibility in C++?

Tags: c++, malloc, new-operator, free, delete-operator

There is a nice comparison of malloc/free and new/delete [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free), and good explanations how malloc() and free() work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work). Obviously, we shall not mix them - use free with new or delete with malloc.

We can see a lot of open source projects, with many contributors, using both of these mechanisms, while respecting the above "no-mix" rule. Usualy, you have only one way in one file (one author, one preference). I have forked such a project and I am adding some functionalities with use of new/delete. But I encounter some curious memory corruptions. Of course, I am probably responsible of them, but.....

That leads me to ask some "naive" questions :

1. Can I have both mechanisms malloc/free and new/delete in the same compilation unit (*.o) - of course, respecting the "no-mix" rule ?
2. Can I interleave the two mechanisms, like in this code ?

   ```
   int *a = (int *) malloc (1000 * sizeof int);

   int *b = new int[1000];

   // some code

   free a;

   delete[] b;
   ```

Comment: Yes but you shouldn't even be using `new` or `malloc` in your own code; use smart pointers like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: I think that is legal.

Comment: Do you ensure not to ever call `malloc()` and `free()` for a type having a constructor or destructor? These calls would not execute the constructor and destructor of your class and may thus be a cause of problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can interleave them - just use a deallocation function matching the one used for allocation. The problem only arises if you use a wrong deallocation function.

Note that it's not that easy when you have several libraries - those might use different heaps and so even though you use a right named function it might happen to be implemented in the wrong module and so use the wrong heap which will drive you right into undefined behavior. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19131623/57428) for a better idea of what I'm talking about here.

Comment: And bear in mind that `malloc` can only be used for POD data types, because it doesn't run constructors.

Comment: @Angew you can still use `malloc` you just have to use placement `new` and call the destructor yourself. `T* p = ::new(std::malloc(sizeof(T))) T(some, args); p->~T(); std::free(p);`

Comment: @Simple Well, yes. But then the question is why.

Comment: @Simple: You've omitted the `malloc()` return value null check.

Comment: @Angew you're right you wouldn't write it if you have another choice but sometimes a C library will `malloc` the memory for you and you have to do it this way.